# Does JavaScript keep firing the if statement on scroll when it already fired once?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I made 2 fixed on scroll headers:

```js
var header = document.getElementsByClassName("header");

function headerChange(){
  if(header[1].getBoundingClientRect().top <= 70){
    header[0].classList.add("fixed-removal");
  } else {
  header[0].classList.remove("fixed-removal");
  
  }
  
  if(header[0].getBoundingClientRect().top <= -70){
    header[1].classList.add("fixed-add");
  } else {
  header[1].classList.remove("fixed-add");
  }
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", headerChange);
```

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 2em;
}

.content {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: yellow;}

.header:nth-of-type(1){
  position: fixed;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.header:nth-of-type(2){
  background-color: red;
}

.fixed-removal {
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 0;
}

.fixed-add {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.content:nth-of-type(2){
margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">HEADER 1</header>
<div class="content"></div>
<header class="header">HEADER 2</header>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Everything is working fine... and that's the problem. Now I have only 2 on scroll fixed headers, but when I have more headers, does JavaScript keep firing that `if/else` statement on scroll? I'm worried about CPU performance, and that's why.
I don't want it to run for no reason, only to throttle performance. Especially with that `else` statement.

***No jQuery answers please***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the `scroll` event listener fires all the time you scroll, your function will be called as well.

By using a *throttled* event handler, you can take of a good deal of workload though, and choose at what rate your function should be called.

Here is one using a `setTimeout`, borrowed at:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize#setTimeout

*Note, at the above link you'll find more versions of how to throttle a handler*

Stack snippet

```js
var header = document.getElementsByClassName("header");

function headerChange(){
  if(header[1].getBoundingClientRect().top <= 70){
    header[0].classList.add("fixed-removal");
  } else {
  header[0].classList.remove("fixed-removal");
  
  }
  
  if(header[0].getBoundingClientRect().top <= -70){
    header[1].classList.add("fixed-add");
  } else {
  header[1].classList.remove("fixed-add");
  }
}

(function(timeout) {

  window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollThrottler, false);

  function scrollThrottler() {
    // ignore scroll events as long as an actualScrollHandler execution is in the queue
    if ( !timeout ) {
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        timeout = null;
        actualScrollHandler();
     
       // The actualScrollHandler will execute at a rate of 15fps
       }, 66);
    }
  }

  function actualScrollHandler() {
    // handle the resize event
    headerChange();
  }

}());
```

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 2em;
}

.content {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: yellow;}

.header:nth-of-type(1){
  position: fixed;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.header:nth-of-type(2){
  background-color: red;
}

.fixed-removal {
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 0;
}

.fixed-add {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.content:nth-of-type(2){
margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">HEADER 1</header>
<div class="content"></div>
<header class="header">HEADER 2</header>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The javascript scroll event is triggered for every scrolled pixel*. Which is a *very* heavy event.

You might want this, but then I recommend a [debounce or dethrottle](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) handlers which basically reduces the amount of call to a configurable times per second, so you can optimize between performance and results.

> Dethrottle:
>   [image: Dethrottle]
>   Debounce:
>   [image: Debounce]

If you want to to happen just once, [you can remove the eventhandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134451/call-function-on-scroll-only-once):

```
document.removeEventListener("scroll", headerChange);
```

**Some browsers do it per few pixels, but still an aweful lot.*

Comment: So you mean that I should detach and reattach the event listeners, and only have one function that's an event handler that attaches other functions?

Comment: Don't you mean `document.removeEventListener`?

Comment: Haha yes. And @MWR: No. It's the intensity of the code, not the amount fo functions. I recommend you read up on the dethrottle/debounce, as that'll explain what you're looking for :)